# RadScriptManager and RadRotator

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radrotator

I'm new with this code (Telerik ASP AJAX) there was another guy who is not here anymore, so we can't ask him to help..
There is a page with simple questionary.. it has been working on previous WEB server (based on IIS Windows 7).
After we built the new PC we also installed Win_7 and the same IIS, but the Telerik Version might be freshier.
..
There is a main page with PlaceHolder (PH) with RadScriptManager.
Then, from another code, RadRotator is created and added as a Control to the PH.
..
During debugging everithing is Ok, I can see how the code creates all the elements, creates RadRotator with success, and then the created Rotator is successfully passed to PH container.
''
But at the end of the way there is no Rotator visible at the page.
..
And I can't see it's references to it's script on the page as well.

It should be like that:

```
<script src="http://some path/2016.3.914/Rotator/RadRotator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But there is no such state on the final page.

The IIS is set to Integrated Mode, not Classic. Also the App is under NET4.

Why generally that would be?

If the question is not clear, please, ask me for clarification.

Comment: Would you be able to provide your aspx markup code and its code behind? That way we can better understand your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, sorry, I forgot to report the answer..

The problem was that in new version

> RadScriptManager

should be replaced with

> ScriptManager

.

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by many things and this fix is strange.

- Ensure the Telerik CDN is enabled so you get the URLs as you said you expect. You need the RadScriptManager for this
- Ensure access to those scripts is provided in your network (monitor the network requests, ensure they return 200 or 304, speakwith your network admins otherwise)
- Ensure you are using an official version and not an internal build, only official releases have CDN
- if you are using webresource requests, add `<location>` elements to the web.config to allow anonymous access to the Telerik handlers that fetch the resources